Web API call from Console app returns unauthorised and invalid request url
I have a web api running with base url http://localhost:8082/
I am creating a C# Consol Application which does a corn job and will communicate web api to push some messages using below snippet
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(“http://localhost:8082/”);
var response = client.GetAsync(“api/UpdateMessage/?status=new”).Result;
Console.WriteLine(response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);

UpdateMessage controller’s Get method is marked with AllowAnonymous attribute.
Problem
On running the console application I am getting Unauthorized status code. Even though this call seems not to be reaching the api as I had breakpoints in all places of the web api project.
But what is more confusing is the result of the 1st Console WriteLine of the response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString()

http://www.cfauth.com/?cfru=some_hash_value

Why my local host request uri is replaced with this url and why the console application is not able to reach the web api which is running via Visual Studio in specified port.

Space in the url (in front of http)?

@mattsharp Typo

You might want to share your API code (controller)

this call seems not to be reaching the api as I had breakpoints in all places of the web api project. - have you rebuild and force restart the api project? often times the debugger and the actual code is out of sync so the debugger wont fire.

@BagusTesa post your suggestion I tried. no luck it seems…

Your application returned an unauthorized status code. This is because your request is not authenticated correctly. You can check if authentication is configured correctly in your API project, And is the appropriate information included in the request (bear token, etc.)? When you configured authentication, did you configure the callback URL related to oauth? If these are ok, can you provide an example of a simple reproducible API?

@YuningDuan This is happening to my another sample project where authentication is not even configured….

You can try to disable auto redirects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.allowautoredirect?view=net-8.0
using var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false
};
using var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);


I added the property you mentioned in handler. Now I am getting status code as found and the write line of “ Console.WriteLine(response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString());” displays requested url correctly. But the response content is displaying message “you are being redirected to the authentication virtual host”

I don’t have authentication in my web api application where I got the redirect message as I mentioned in previous comment
